# remove double quotes from factors in a dataframe

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I got a dataframe to work on where I have a bunch of variables as factors in quotation marks like `""x1""`.

`str(df)` gives me something like this:

```
$ x : Factor w/ 10 Levels "\"\"x1\"\"",..: 1 7 9 ...
```

I tried to get rid of the quotation marks with the `gsub()` function but that didn´t work. Probably because I don´t know what to insert as pattern? Would be great if somebody can solve this puzzle and maybe explain to me if the `"\"\"x1\"\""` is the solution to this?

An example for the dataframe would look like this:

```
structure(list(Sent = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("\"\"Opted out\"\"", 
"\"\"Yes\"\""), class = "factor"), Responded = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("\"\"Complete\"\"", "\"\"No\"\"", 
"\"\"Partial\"\""), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("Sent", 
"Responded"))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it will be good if you can provide reproducible example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
vec = c('""x1""', '""x2""', '""x3""')
vec =  factor(vec)

levels(vec) <- gsub('["\\]', "", levels(vec))

#> vec
#[1] x1 x2 x3
#Levels: x1 x2 x3
```

---

- See how I would use `'` as wrapper, when I want to use `"` inside a string.
- Another problem it didn't work for you was probably because you didn't use the levels attribute but rather the factor variable itself.
- Factor variables are internally stored as `1, 2, 3,...` numbers.

---

As you now have provided data, you can use: (`df1` being your data with the factor columns)

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(vec){ levels(vec) <- gsub('["\\]',"",levels(vec)); vec})
```

Comment: Thanks! So how do I know to put `'["\\]'` as pattern?

Comment: `levels(vec) <- gsub('"', "", levels(vec), fixed=TRUE)` also works.

Comment: `"` and \ is the stuff you want to remove right? \ needs to be escaped into \\. In order to become good at this stuff, take a deep dive into regEx. It's super worthy!!!